# Excel VBA - Values Not Returning From Function

Tags: excel, function, vba, arguments

I'm trying to get an Excel function to return more arguments than are passed to it initially.  It's been a while since I used Excel VBA, but I was wondering if it is possible to do this?  Here is the code I've been developing.

The function ("SelectColumn") needs to return 6 values, and I've got them as arguments in the code below.
Many thanks for any help.

```
Sub match_names3()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim strRow, strCol As Integer
 Dim UpBound, LowBound As Range

 Dim strUpBoundRow, strUpBoundColumn, strLowBoundRow, strLowBoundColumn As Integer
 Dim CompareRange_alum_names As Range
 Dim CompareRange_bio_names As Range
 Dim alum As Variant, bio As Variant
 Dim AlumCount, BioCount As Long
 strRow = 2
 strCol = 8
 strUpBoundRow = 0
 strUpBoundColumn = 0
 strLowBoundRow = 0
 strLowBoundColumn = 0

 SelectColumn strRow, strCol, strUpBoundRow, strUpBoundColumn, strLowBoundRow, strLowBoundColumn


 Set CompareRange_alum_names = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(strUpBoundRow, strUpBoundColumn) & ":" & Cells(strLowBoundRow, strLowBoundColumn))


 strRow = 2
 strCol = 17
 strUpBoundRow = 0
 strUpBoundColumn = 0
 strLowBoundRow = 0
 strLowBoundColumn = 0

 SelectColumn strRow, strCol, strUpBoundRow, strUpBoundColumn, strLowBoundRow, strLowBoundColumn


 Set CompareRange_alum_names = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(strUpBoundRow, strUpBoundColumn) & ":" & Cells(strLowBoundRow, strLowBoundColumn))

 AlumCount = 2
     For Each alum In CompareRange_alum_names

      BioCount = 2
         For Each bio In CompareRange_bio_names

             If bio.Value = alum.Value Then

             Cells(AlumCount, 19).Value = Cells(BioCount, 16)
             End If
          BioCount = BioCount + 1
          Next bio

     AlumCount = AlumCount + 1
     Next alum


 End Sub



 Function SelectColumn(ByVal strRow As Integer, ByVal strCol As Integer, ByVal strUpBoundRow As Integer, ByVal strUpBoundColumn As Integer, ByVal strLowBoundRow As Integer, ByVal strLowBoundColumn As Integer)

 Dim UpBound As Range
 Dim LowBound As Range

 Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(strRow, strCol).Select

 If ActiveCell.Row > 1 Then
     If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0)) Then
     Set UpBound = ActiveCell
     Else
     Set UpBound = ActiveCell.End(xlUp)
     End If
 Else
     Set UpBound = ActiveCell
 End If
 strUpBoundRow = UpBound.Row
 strUpBoundColumn = UpBound.Column
 MsgBox ("strUpBoundRow " & strUpBoundRow)
 MsgBox ("strUpBoundColumn " & strUpBoundColumn)


 If ActiveCell.Row < Rows.Count Then
     If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)) Then
     Set LowBound = ActiveCell
     Else
     Set LowBound = ActiveCell.End(xlDown)
     End If
 Else
     Set LowBound = ActiveCell
 End If
 strLowBoundRow = LowBound.Row
 strLowBoundColumn = LowBound.Column
 MsgBox ("strLowBoundRow " & strLowBoundRow)
 MsgBox ("strLowBoundColumn " & strLowBoundColumn)


 Range(UpBound, LowBound).Select


 Set UpBound = Nothing
 Set LowBound = Nothing

 End Function
```

Comment: Pass your parameters ByRef and not ByVal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further elucidate Tim Williams' comment, passing values ByRef means a reference to the (memory) location of the variables will be given to the SelectColumn function. Inside the SelectColumn function, when one of those variables is changed, the function will change the value of the variable at that reference, i.e. the original variable.

When you pass a variable ByVal, a duplicate of that variable is generated. This exists only within the SelectColumn function. If you change it inside SelectColumn it changes this duplicate, rather than the original.

Edit:

You'll need to change your declarations. When you declare the following:

```
Dim strRow, strCol As Integer
```

You expect strRow and strCol to both be integers, however, strRow is a variant, strCol is an integer (This goads me greatly). You need to declare these as follows:

```
Dim strRow as Integer, _
    strCol as integer
```

Similarly with a number of your other declarations.

Comment: Many thanks.  I've made the change; however, Now I am getting a "Compile error: ByRef argument type mismatch"
Would this be a datatype mismatch?

Comment: See the amended answer (needed to include code so didn't put it here, even though it doesn't specifically pertain to the question).

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help - I did the same and found it to be the solution.